# bash command piping (and php): How to check from command line each php file in all subdirs?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop recursively through my project dirs and subdirs and check syntax from php command line.

I'm able to list all php files using

```
find ./ -name '*.php'
```

and I'm able to che check a single php php as

```
php -l ./full/path/to/file/filename.php
```

But I'm not ble to make them working together

```
 find ./ -name '*.php' | php -l
```

This really doesn't do any check. I tried forcing a syntax error in a file but this tell me every time:

```
No syntax errors detected in -
```

**How to correctly pipe each file name for php syntax checking?**

Feel free to adjust the title and/or the question, my english is not so good.

EDIT 1: I googled on stackoverflow and tried these, but without success

```
$ find ./ -name '*.php' | xargs -0 "php -l"
xargs: argument line too long
```

EDIT 2: another try

```
$ find ./ -name '*.php' -exec php -l
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Comment: It's the difference between `echo filename | php -l` and `php -l filename`.  Because `php -l` does not use standard input to read the names of the files you want to process, the former doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run php command with each file name with,

```
find ./ -name '*.php' -exec php -l {} \;
```

Comment: This works, great! Can you expand the answer explaining why my command was not working? And, what does it mean the syntax `{} |;`  ?

Comment: It's all in the man page.  Have you tried reading `man find`?  Briefly, `-exec` is the option for running a command on the files that `find` returns, and is needed before your `php` command.  `{}` is the placeholder for the found file name, and the escaped semicolon `\;` terminates the command.  Your command pipes the file names into the **standard input** of php, which is different from them being specified on the command line.

Comment: @rojomoke Thanks for the additions. Regarding `\;`, it terminates the command but it also runs what comes after `-exec` with each finding of `find`. When you replace it with `\+` it will make a list of the findings and pass it to the command, like `php -l file1.php file2.php ...`.

Comment: @realtebo Your command was probably not working because `php` expects a file name after `-l` parameter, not input from `STDIN`. Regarding `xargs`, since `php -l` expects one file name at a time you should do `find ./ -name '*.php' | xargs -n 1 php -l`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a shell loop:

```
for file in $(find ./ -name '*.php')
do
  php -l "${file}"
done
```

Comment: This works, great! Can you expand the answer explaining why my command was not working?

Comment: It should be semicolon separated like `for file in $(find ./ -name '*.php'); do   php -l "${file}"; done`. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html.